# Can't get ics file to download and open calendar on iOS

Tags: php, ios, forms, calendar, icalendar

I wrote a simple php script to dynamically write an .ics file. The script is called when a HTML form is submitted:

```
<form id="m1-remind-form" action="/php/make_ics.php" method="get">
```

On the desktop it works fine. The file is downloaded, and when the user opens it the calendar event is added. On an iOS device with mobile Safari nothing happens. Even if I just directly link to a valid ics file, nothing happens. The mime-type, text/calendar, has been added to the server. The php gives these headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename .".ics");
```

I've messed around with other mime-types and various header settings. Nothing seems to work.

I found a site where their dynamically created ics file downloads with mobile Safari and opens Calendar just fine and has the user experience I am looking for. See here: http://m.anderson.ucla.edu/today

They are using a .NET script to make the ics file, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Seems like it could be a server(IIS) issue, but we don't know what it could be. Any suggestions? I am at a loss here.

Comment: Open the ics file in a text editor and see if anything looks out of place such as a php error. Typically anything output to the browser will be included with the download.

Comment: Thanks, but have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Form button was not submitting on mobile Safari. On the desktop it did submit. Had to force submit on mobile with javascript.

```
btn.addEventListener('touchend', function(){form.submit()});
```

Not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

`header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$filename .".ics");`

Comment: Please include some more information on why they should

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.